# What is the largest number of collective variables used in a metadynamics simulation?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, free-energy, plumed, enhanced-sampling, collective-variable

Metadynamics is usually used to construct 1D or 2D free-energy surfaces. There seem to be a few examples for 3D free-energy surfaces:

[Paper 1: Exploring the Free Energy Landscape of Solutes Embedded in Lipid Bilayers](https://doi.org/10.1021/jz4007993)

[Paper 2: Exploring Complex Protein−Ligand Recognition Mechanisms with Coarse Metadynamics](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp803936q).

Has anyone ever seen a 4D or 5D free-energy surface constructed with metadynamics?
If so, how did they manage to converge the simulation?

Answer (score 3):

[This paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.5b00846) from 2015 describes a *modified* metadynamics method (parallel-bias metadynamics) by which the authors demonstrate enhanced sampling over *six* collective variables for the tryptophan cage system<sup>1</sup>. They do not mention any attempts using plain metadynamics to get anywhere near that number of CVs, so I assume (from silence) that 3D is as far as plain metadynamics has went.

Even before worrying about convergence, I think you'd have a problem simply calculating the metadynamics bias. Doing so "by hand" (storing all visited points and calculating the gradient from each previous point at a new step) is very slow. But if you try to deposit the weights on a grid, the number of grid points needed increases exponentially with dimensionality. Storing 50^3 floats takes 50 KB of RAM; storing 50^6 floats takes 62.5 GB of RAM, which you won't have per processor on almost any cluster. The paper I linked above gets around this by marginalising the landscape onto each CV separately. Somehow the authors can reconstruct the whole landscape afterwards; I'm not sure exactly how they do it, and I'm keen to learn.

---

<sup>1</sup> Sadly, they lacked six-dimensional paper to print their six-dimensional free energy landscape upon. More funding needed, surely.